# In one year, what's the maximum I can contribute to RRSP, from past unused contribution room?

Tags: canada, retirement-plan, rrsp

[My dad is 63 and lives in Ontario.](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/106624/40269).  He maxed out his TFSA. His annual pre-tax income is [$50K](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/106624/40269). Here is a screen-shot of his CRA online account:

[image: CRA account]

He  never opened a RRSP, thus the $100K must've been carried forward.

1. Am I correct that  min(18% of APTI, $26500) doesn't apply to carried-forward unused contribution room?
2. Let's assume that 2020 first federal tax bracket is $13 000 and Ontario is $11 000. [Then my dad can contribute to RRSP 50 000 – yearly tax deductions – 11 000](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/112132/40269) = 39 000 – yearly tax deductions. Did I understand  [Wealthsimple](https://www.wealthsimple.com/en-ca/learn/rrsp-contribution-deduction-limit#rrsp_deduction_limit_vs_contribution_limit)?

> The RRSP deduction limit for 2019 is 18% of a taxpayer’s pre-tax earned income for 2018 or $26,500 **whichever is less.**
>
> [...]
>
> ### RRSP deduction limit vs contribution limit
>
> The RRSP deduction limit differs from the contribution limit as it does not take into account past unused RRSP contributions. The RRSP deduction limit is always 18% of pre-tax earnings from the previous tax year, or the CRA established limit, whichever is less.
>
> ### Example contribution room calculation
>
> Your contribution limit is the total of this years deduction limit and any unused contribution room you have. Here's an example: Jim is employed full-time and in 2018, he made $50,000 pre-tax. His employer does not provide any pension plan. Here’s what his calculation would look like: 18% of $50,000 or $26,500, whichever is less. Let's do the math. $50,000 x 18%=$9,000. That is less than the maximum limit of $26,500 so his RRSP deduction limit is $9,000.
>
> Jim doesn’t have any pension adjustments, so his total deduction limit is $9,000. If Jim makes a $5000 contribution to his RRSP, he'll have $4,000 unused eligible contribution room.
>
> In 2020, he'll be able to carry forward that $4,000 and add it to his deduction room. If his deduction room remains $9,000, he will be able to contribute a total of $15,000 to his RRSP ($9,000 + $4,000 carry forward=$16,600).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the key line from your sources:

"Your contribution limit is the total of this years deduction limit and any unused contribution room you have."

That is: You can contribute the total of all of your historical unused room, + the new room you created this year from additional employment income.