# Where can I see break-down of total federal and Ontario non-refundable tax credits?

Tags: income-tax, canada

[Please see my 63 y.o. Ontarian dad's cash flow.](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/106624/40269). I screen-shot, but rounded the values from his 2018 Notice of Assessment.

1. Where can I see  tax credits broken down? I want  see them so that I can  resubmit TD1

   > form to his employer so that less income tax is deducted from his paycheque.<sup>1</sup>

   Notice of Assessment beneath doesn't itemize tax credits refunded him.

   [image]
2. Reddit recommended https://sherpa.tax/dashboard?pg=1, but it looks wrong? Dad clearly was refunded $5000 tax credits, more than $227.42

   [image]

<sup>1</sup>Gill, Madura. [*Personal Finance*, 4th Canadian Edition 2019](https://www.amazon.ca/Personal-Finance-Canadian-Pearson-Package/dp/013485201X/ref=pd_cp_14_1?pd_rd_w=c29n6&pf_rd_p=64a84aa4-b549-4445-9bf3-48bdeed5f24a&pf_rd_r=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41&pd_rd_r=ac94fdf8-0331-4f63-9fd4-08392967896d&pd_rd_wg=LkHyc&pd_rd_i=013485201X&psc=1&refRID=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41). p. 129. Last paragraph.

Comment: I don't understand - why do you think the deductions 'should be less'? This impacts your first and second questions.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon sorry. you're right. i jumped the gun. i shall see the break-down first.

Comment: You have his Notice of Assessment. Do you have his actual tax return? That will have all the details. The line numbers on the NoA correspond to line numbers on the tax return. Even if it was done online (I recommend UFile) it all uses these line numbers as sections and headings.

Comment: Also, the information you seek will not serve the purpose you want. The numbers on a TD1 don't come from a tax assessment. They come from facts like "do you have a disabled child" or "are you over 65" which you can answer without this information. There isn't a way on your TD1 to further decrease withholdings based on a preference or prediction.